Prove $GH \parallel BC$ in olympiad geometry problem
Earlier today a question was asked but the poster showed no work and the question was downvoted and quickly deleted. The situation posed was as in the left diagram: a triangle $ABC$ has equal segments $BE, CF$ cut from each side such that the segment $EF$ connecting them is also equal. Above $EF$, angle bisectors $EH, FG$ are formed. Prove $GH \parallel BC$.
This question is from some olympiad.
Edit: The original motivation of this post was that I suspected the problem was supposed to be solved using angle bisector theorems and substitutions on $EF$, but I wanted to find a proof by dilation. I found one and posted to check a part of the proof I felt was fuzzy. @X-Rui found a flaw in the logic, @aschepler showed the proof was only good for isosceles $ABC$, so the dilation approach has failed. I've now posted the straightforward solution indicated above.
Alternative solutions are welcome.


I'm not sure about $GH \parallel EF$, and I can't find the butterfly. I'm rusty at olympiad geometry (never good to begin with) though so I could be wrong XD

@X-Rui: look at the triangles on $GE,EB$, they are similar. These are the left wings. The ones on $HF,FC$ are the right wings.

So which pair(s) of shapes are similar exactly? I can see the triangle on $GE$ is similar to the one on $EB$, and the same on the other side. But I think they have different ratios, so the two butterflies, each as a whole, are not similar to each other.

@X-Rui: you're right, the left triangles are similar, and the right triangles are similar, but I do not know that the ratios are similar. And they must not be, for if they were the approach would work, but I just constructed the thing in Geogebra and GH is not parallel to EF. Back to the drawing board.

Sorry, a dilation doesn't work. You are correct that the dilation $A(\frac{AE}{AG})$ maps $F$ to $C$. But it maps $E$ to $B$ if and only if:
$$\begin{align*} & \frac{AB}{AE} = \frac{AE}{AG} = \frac{AC}{AF} \\
 \iff& \frac{AB-AE}{AE} = \frac{AC-AF}{AF} \\
\iff& \frac{BE}{AE} = \frac{CF}{AF} \\
\iff& AE = AF \\
\iff& AE+BE = AF+CF \\
\iff& AB = AC
\end{align*} $$
that is, the original triangle is isosceles.

This should've been a comment. Not an answer.

@Euclid I posted specifically because my logic felt soft. This answer is helping sharpen exactly the problematic part of my wrong proof and would be impossible to format decently in a comment, it's on target, I appreciate the answer.

@Euclid I considered making a comment, but it's not really about improving the question and is about the main ask. And there didn't seem to be anything else a good answer really would say, since modifying the same approach didn't seem like it would work out.

Although the dilation approach isn't working out, the straightforward strategy using angle bisector theorems and substitution of $EF=BE=CF$ does:
$\frac{AH}{HF}=\frac{AE}{EF}=\frac{AE}{EB}=k_1$
$\frac{AG}{GE}=\frac{AF}{EF}=\frac{AF}{CF}=k_2$
We thus have chains of ratios running down each side. If we can bring them into register to prove that $\frac{AG}{AB}=\frac{AH}{AC}$ we prove by Thales theorem that $GH \parallel BC$.
For any ratio $k=\frac{x}{y}$, $\frac{x}{x+y}=\frac{k}{k+1}$, so:
$AH=\frac{k_1}{k_1+1}AF$, $AF=\frac{k_2}{k_2+1}AC$, and $AH=\frac{k_2}{k_2+1}\frac{k_1}{k_1+1}AC$. Similarly, $AG=\frac{k_2}{k_2+1}\frac{k_1}{k_1+1}AB$.
Thus, $\frac{k_2}{k_2+1}\frac{k_1}{k_1+1}=\frac{AG}{AB}=\frac{AH}{AC}$, as desired.
